# download csv file downloads whole aspx page

Tags: c#, csv, download

I'm trying to download datatable as csv. I'm using following function.

```
public void DtDown(DataTable dt)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0},", col.ColumnName));
        }
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}", row[0], row[1]));
        }


            string attachment = "attachment; filename=sample.csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());

    }
```

However this code prompt me to download aspx page,not the csv file. This happens in chrome browser only.

Am i missing something? Can you please suggest any modifications which resolves the issue.

Comment: How is the method called?

Comment: @LukeVo : Just by using DtDown(ds.Tables[0]);